# Password protect android app

Tags: android, passwords

I have an application which I am developing. I need to password protect it, i.e. a password needs to be entered before allowing access to the main content.

Password can be stored locally in the Java file.

***LoginActivity.java***

```
package com.example.capitacustomerfactsheets;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        final EditText passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
        final Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        loginButton .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(passWord.getText().toString().equals("123456")) {
                    final Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                    myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

***activity_login.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editpassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make a Activity `LoginActivity` which is the default Activity, In this Activity you have a EditText and a OK Button. When the user enters the correct pw and hits ok startActivity(Main.class...) else make a Toast which says unable to start

Comment: Thanks A.S.  Can you please help me with the code for this?

Comment: I am sure you can make it on your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        final EditText passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
        final Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(passWord.getText().toString().equals("123456")) {
                    final Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                    myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(LoginActivity.this,your new activity.class));
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: App will not load after adding this to it. have added code to original post - please can you look at it for me?

Comment: no errors in eclipse - but get "Unfortunately App Name has stopped" error

Comment: ok i got problem you haven't use "setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);" this

Comment: Where should that go?

Comment: still the same error - no errors in eclipse that I can see

Comment: have added up to date code to original post above now - thank you for your help so far, it is really appreciated!

Comment: is there space no between "loginButton.setOnClickListener". got it ?

Comment: there is a space there - have tried with space and without a space but same error

Comment: what was name off your second activity ?

Comment: once password has been entered it should goto MainActivity

Comment: ok then all looks fine. so try to get error log. it will helps lot. without its not possible. and ones you get log post here so i can see.

Comment: and post your AndroidManifest.xml file also

Comment: think I have figured it out - super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); was missing

Comment: thank you very much Borad - I cannot thank you enough! it works great now!